# bash script for substituition array does not give expected output.previous value being overwritten

Tags: arrays, bash, associative-array

```
declare -a args=()
args["p4"]=3
args["ifile"]=4
echo ${args["p4"]}
```

I am getting output

```
4
```

Why previous array entry is being overwritten?

Comment: Take a look at option `-A` of declare. See: `help declare`.

Answer (score 0):

Just so there's an answer here:

Using `declare -a` specifies that you are declaring an indexed array. Any non-numeric indices will be interpreted as a zero. Instead, use `declare -A` which initializes an associative array. Note however, that only a few shells support associative arrays.

From the man page:

```
    Options which set attributes:
      -a    to make NAMEs indexed arrays (if supported)
      -A    to make NAMEs associative arrays (if supported)
```